# Angular Material - Not closing Material snackbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

I am using Angular and Angular Material version 5.

Is there a way to keep the snackbar open?

For example, if an error happens, open a snackbar and set a duration or a timeout on that snackbar to be closed after 5 seconds. If another error happens, within those 5 seconds, how can I instead of closing this one, and opening another snackbar, to just increase duration of this one for few seconds?

Here is stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4ww8y

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't answer the original question but, if you want a snackbar with indefinite duration:
    snackbar.open("Message", "Action", {duration: undefined});

Answer (score 3):

you can set duration 0 to snackbar option

```
{ duration: 0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try it the other way round:

Set a very high duration on the timeout, then, if no error occurs during the next 5 seconds, close it with the `dismiss` method

https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api

You can add a custom component inside the snackbar, instead of just text. That custom component can be in charge of updating the message

https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples

Btw, in your stackblitz, the snackbar never closes because you declared duration as

```
duration: 5000;
```

instead of

```
duration = 5000;
```

Answer (score 1):

simply ignore duration element. Then snackbar will never get closed

Answer (score 0):

Only one snack-bar can ever be opened at one time. If a new snackbar is opened while a previous message is still showing, the older message will be automatically dismissed.

Instead, You can use localstorage to save last error message and combine both error messages in single snack-bar and clear the localstorage after dismissing the second snackbar.

Comment: I don't see that to be the case. In fact, I am currently trying to solve an issue where multiple are opened at the same time.